# Confusion between primed and unprimed coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems

While deriving Ampere's law in Magnetostatics we come across a term $\nabla\times J(r') = 0$ and the reasoning we give is because current density is only a function of primed coordinates hence it's derivatives w.r.t unprimed ones are zero. What I want to know is how are these two coordinates different? I understand frames of reference but what I don't understand is the mathematical difference between these two frames if there is any. As much as I can tell if we can find a relation between the primed and unprimed coordinates we can apply chain rule and make the derivation for $\nabla . B=0$ more cumbersome. However it would be nice to know how these two coordinates are different and if there is really no way to find a relation between them(maybe for well defined current distributions a relation could be found out?)

Comment: These coordinates are taken to be independent, you define the electric current density on some points r' of the space (for example the set of points forming the volume of a conducting wire, V) but you are interested to take the derivatives in points of the space independently on the value that r' can take. Of course the unprimed coordinates will take the same values of the primed ones in V, but they are conceptually two independent set of variables.

Comment: Are you suggesting in any way that primed coordinates only exist within the current distribution? @NNec

Comment: Also is it really impossible to define $J$ as a function of $r$?